# Where is the Save As Dailog Box?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In the old version, I had more control over how I would backup my table and data.

After selecting the database and table, I would click on the Export tab, and at the bottom was a "Save as file" checkbox.  From there I would get the Microsoft Windows Explorer "Save As" dialog box and had more control where to save my .sql files.

This latest version of phpmyadmin no longer gives me that option.  I am given the options "Quick" and Custom."  Choosing Custom gives me the option to "Save output to a file", lets me specify a "File name template" which is set to @TABLE@ and the character set.  It does not give me the option to choose the save location.

When I click "Go", it opens up the output in my editpad light but through the browser's default downloads folder, and it is frustrating to have to either copy and paste the text in a new file or navigate through a series of folders every time.

I am using Version: 4.2.5, latest stable version: 4.5.0.2 and latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome: Version 45.0.2454.101 m

Comment: Not sure what the previous version was.  Here is a screen shot of what I used before.  https://account.buyhttp.com/images/tutorials/cpanel/x3/phpmyadmin/slide13.gif

Comment: This looks like version 2.11.11. I tried it with the same Google Chrome as you, and I did not get prompted.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a save dialog in Google Chrome, open its Settings page (can be done by visiting chrome://chrome/settings/). Then click on "Advanced settings" and you'll see a Downloads section. Tick the option "Ask where to save each file before downloading".

Comment: It is checked off for "Ask where to save each file before downloading."

Comment: Mine also is checked, and testing with phpMyAdmin 4.2.5 I get a save dialog when exporting. Did you try another web site that permits you to download something, to compare the behavior?

Comment: Ok so I just checked in Firefox.  I am able to receive the "Save As" dialog box.  Back in Chrome, I am also able to receive the dialog box at the Download Firefox homepage, but still not PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I don't observe the same behavior as you do on my Chrome. Could you try Chrome on another machine? Also, do you have any Chrome extensions?